# Como baixar arquivo ao invés de abrir em nova aba?

Tags: javascript

**Pessoal tenho uma página com vários arquivos pdf e quando clica em algum é aberto um modal com um formulário para preenchimento, após a confirmação de envio o arquivo abre duas vezes em uma nova aba, eu precisaria que não abrisse 2 vez, mas sim que ele baixasse automaticamente.**

```
var fileLink, modalForm;
var showModal = true;

jQuery(function() {

    // Modal
    modalForm = jQuery('#modal');

    jQuery('.post-attachments')
        .find('a')
        .click(function() {

            fileLink = jQuery(this);

                  modalForm.modal(); 
                
        

            return false;


        })



});

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    
    downloadFile()
    
    }, false );

function downloadFile() {
    

    showModal = false;
    
    
        window.open(fileLink.attr('href'));
        modalForm.modal('hide');


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adiciona o atributo download na tua tag

```
<a href="exemplo.png" download>
```

se quiser colocar uma sugestão de nome na imagem

```
<a href="/path/to/image.png" download="exemplo.png">
```

Comment: Tem alguma forma de fazer diretamente ai no js? Sem ter que adicionar o atributo download na tag.